# Video Stitching of overlapped videos

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Hello I have multiple videos which overlap at some time and want to stitch these videos to get a single video stream.

for example below are three videos where video 1 and video 2 overlap at some time[image]

Now I wanted the final o/p to be

[image]

Where initially video 1 frames are read and written to the video writer object until there is an overlap. Once there is an overlap the view switches from video 1 or video 2 based on some decisions(which is not my question). Once the overlap ends the frames from video 2 are read and written as the video 1 frames are completed. And finally when they are no frames left from video 2, frames from video 3 are read and written.

My question is how to read and write the overlapped videos as i wanted to have the frames from video or video 2 for the overlapped period. The problem I am facing is how to identify the overlap while reading and writing the frames without checking the video content.

I am finding the overlapped time by analyzing the time stamps and also getting the video indices for which there is an overlap. So, how can I use this information to read and write frames for overlapped videos. Below is the on how I am getting the information which will be used for writing

```
 def dict_cam(key,values):
    return {key[i]:values[i] for i in range (len(key))}

 users=dict_cam(indices,intervals) # Creates dictionary with videos indices as keys(indices) with their start and end time as their values(intervals).

 overlapping = [ [i,j,x,y] for i,x in users.iteritems() for j,y in users.iteritems() if x is not y and x[1]>y[0] and x[0]<y[0] ] # For identifying overlapping.


 for x in overlapping

   camera=[x[0]]
   camera.append(x[1])
   begin=x[2][0]
   end=x[2][1]
   begg=x[3][0]
   ens=x[3][1]
   if begin < begg and begg<end:
       overlap.append(begg)
   if ens < end:
       overend.append(ens)
  else:
      overend.append(end)


over_rang=overlap + overend
```

Where, camera is a list of video indices where there is an overlap, and over_rang is a list which contains the duration of the overlap.

Before starting video writing I am sorting all the video indices with their start time.

I do not want to analyze the video content rather use the information about the overlapped time and the indices where there is a overlap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two overlapping videos frame by frame to form a single frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430281/combine-two-overlapping-videos-frame-by-frame-to-form-a-single-frame)

Comment: are your timestamps global (shared clock) or local (each video starts at its own timestamp 0)? If yo don't KNOW the overlap, you'll have to analyse the video and find common "events" (like the clap in movies). Imho you are looking for some kind of timestamp synchronization.

Comment: I have the time stamps which are the system time stamps in HH-MM-SS format. Generally videos are recorded from a mobile phone so the time stamps are time from the mobile phone.

Comment: you've recorded multiple videos from overlapping timestamp regions on the same device? Maybe I've misunderstood you, are the timestamp regions not overlapping? Then they're worth nothing for your stitching. Can you post sample frames from your videos with timestamps?

Comment: They are not recorded from the same device but from different devices. for example video1 is started from 19-13-28 and ends at 19-13-45 and video 2 starts at 19-13-33 and ends at 19-13-59 and video 3 starts at 19-14-05 and ends at 19-14-20. So there is an overlap between video 1 and video 2 at 19-13-33 till 19-13-45.(No time synchronization is to be considered but just only the overlap of time)

Comment: so the timestamps are coarsely synchronized (if all the device clocks are going 'right'). So where's the problem? For each frame you know the global (coarse) timestamp in each video... just load frames from the first video until the frame timestamp matches the first frame timestamp of the second video?!?

Comment: The problem I am facing is getting to know the timestamp of the frames while reading the frames. And also to know the timestamp of which video the stamp matches.