# (no accepted answer) How to merge 2 overlapping videos into one video using ffmpeg or opencv?

Tags: node.js, opencv, ffmpeg

Merging two videos is easy, been answered couple of times. What I have is multiple overlapping videos. A video might have overlaps with video before it. Meaning if video 1 covers 1-5 timeline then video 2 may overlap 1, and cover 3 to 8. Merging them as is would result in 1-5|3-8, when i need 1-8 only.

Videos are alphabetically sorted.

My general idea of solution is...

- grab last frame of the video
- if it's first video continue
- if it's not first video, ie. 2nd, search for frame saved in previous steps frame by frame
- if it reaches to last frame of current video then there is no overlap continue
- if it founds a frame then clip 2nd video up to that frame inclusive and then go to next frame
- once all videos have been analyzed, merge them into one video.

I need to translate this to ffmpeg commands. Or opencv if that's a better tool.

If there is better way of doing that, I'm interested in that too.

Comment: I dont think ffmpeg can do what you want easily. Should just start with opencv.  and the routing should be  final_img_mat = \sum alpha_id * image_id_video_id.  not very sure what you up to or whats the difficulty in it.

Comment: I want to merge two videos. Videos can have overlap. My problem is I've zero experience with opencv.

Comment: post the video on some web. i`ll help you write a simple code to combine them

Comment: BTW if just 2 stream, you can use FFMEPG. but if more and have 1-5|3-8 sort of or operation. just use opencv.   for merge 2 stream you can use this  :  ffmpeg -i input.mov -i overlay.mov 
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-10/TB[a]; 
                 [0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):shortest=1[out]" 
-map [out] -map 0:a 
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-c:a copy 
output.mov

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxhjOGIcXv4

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tIOE1FNBew

Comment: 2 videos  with some frames that identical and overlap. I want to merge them and clip overlapping part in 2nd video

Comment: with ffmpeg you only can do manual offset. with opencv you can auto detect overlap and merge.  I`ll do the manual offset way tmr morning. its close to 1 am in Singapore

Comment: thanks for the help, no problem. If I find solution I'll release it as github repo

Comment: i was very close to doing it with opencv but learned opencv doesn't deal with audio which makes opencv useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

for ffmepg you can use the script below. it tested it. But timing wise, you have to change  of this STARTPTS+5  to +25 in your video.  I put 5 here to test the merging is happening.

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB[top];[0:0][top]overlay=enable='between(t\,10,15)'[out]" -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1        -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output1.mp4
```

Limitation
This one need the source to be long enough which means you need video canvas then use this script to add each video into the canvas.

And there is no fully autonomous way of use it in ffmpeg.

You are right. Opencv cant deal with audio. need 3rd party library support to run concurrently. Before then I have to use ROS to get both sound and vision to the robot system from a webcam. The sound is then process with NLP for natual language user interface and vision is used separately for locozlaiton and mapping.

There is some way to walk around.

First, you use OpenCV template matching or image difference on a local window batch. The smallest error position will give you the correct location A to insert. This should be accurate in terms of mili-second level. (if error is always big, then it means there is no overlap and return exception)

Second, based on the correct location obtained from opencv. call system.call to invoke the above script with A parameter as input to do auto merge.

Depends on your application, if you need to do it frequently, write opencv python script to automatic fuse. If just once every month, do it manually with ffmepg  is good enough